# pd.read_Json not producing data frame with correct column headings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have this program that reads a csv files and translates it to a  json file.

Now i am trying to get pandas to read this json file but it is not printing as wanted dataframe and instead it is printing this as almost a row of strings with the column headings inside instead of being at the top.

I am not sure, if i messed up in the translation or if there is some sort of pandas cleaning that i need to do.

If you look at the below code, i have append the column headings, but in the dataframe the headings are being printed in the rows:

Would appreciate any help

```
#Import required files
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

#Open file
with open(InspectionsFile, "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    data = {"Inspections": []}
    for row in reader:
        data["Inspections"].append({"ACTIVITY DATE":row[0], "OWNER ID":row[1], "OWNER NAME":row[2], "FACILITY ID":row[3],
                                         })

#Open a new File and dumb JSON format
JsonFile = input('Enter a filename to save in Json format: ')
with open(JsonFile, "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4) 
    print(" A new file has been created with json format for the database")
    
df = pd.read_json (JsonFile)

pandas is reading this like:
0   {'ACTIVITY DATE': '08/23/2018', 'OWNER ID': 'O...
1   {'ACTIVITY DATE': '12/06/2017', 'OWNER ID': 'O...
2   {'ACTIVITY DATE': '06/23/2017', 'OWNER ID': 'O...
```

Comment: Could you please show us how the JSON-File looks like. Maybe you could try to use `pd.read_json(JsonFile, orient=index)`.

Comment: Thank you mos, i did pd.json_normalize on the first csv file and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) instead of `pandas.read_json`. I think that that will solve your problem.

Comment: I had previously tried this, and i get an error as follows: 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Thank you, i just tried pandas.json_normalise on the original file and it worked.